# Android - using Httppost to pass some data from android apps to servlet, but it becomes null in servlet

Tags: android, database, servlets, http-post

```
//Here is my Eclipse, suppose i already get the heartvalue and oxygenvalue in other method call
private OnClickListener upload = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("o2",oxygenvalue));
        namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("heart",heartvalue));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www2.comp.polyu.edu.hk:8080/08065312D/servlet/ServletTest"); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d("d", response.toString());
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String reading = sb.toString();
            TextView lbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test4);
            lbl.setText(reading);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

//Here is my servlet

public class FypServletTest extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://mysql.comp.polyu.edu.hk:3306/", "08065312d", "xxxx");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("USE 08065312d");
            String id = "2";
            String oxygenvalue = request.getParameter("o2");
            String heartvalue = request.getParameter("heart");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query="insert into Test values('"+id+"','"+oxygenvalue+"','"+heartvalue+"');";
            int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }
          catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

}
}

//I can successfully add a new row into the DB, but the parameters(the reading) becomes null. I tried to change the program by directly println(request.getParmater("o2")) in servelet but not saving to db, the result are the same too(the reading becomes null null in the servlet). So I doubt that i can't get the parameter passed to the servlet or there is problem with the method request.getParmater, so what's going wrong?

//The problem I am having is sending the POST variable, which continually seems to be null
//I have been looking at forums for the past week, and all the httppost examples follow this almost exactly. I would appreciate any help that you are willing to give. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding a log line to your catch {} block in the android app (and servlet for that matter). You should never just catch Exception and not print it out or do nothing else with it. You might be getting an IO Exception that isn't letting the POST happen or some security setting like not having the INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes i have added the permission in manifest file before,

Comment: and how to add log line in catch {}block? since i am very beginner in java and android

Comment: Add "e.printStackTrace();" in your catch(Exception e){} blocks to make sure errors are printed. This is definitely the first thing you should be trying to give the code the chance to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: i have added it and where i can see those log in eclipse?

Comment: and i think i can getting the data passed to db and the response back from servlet, it may not be get into the exception
my main concern is the data passed to the servlet become null, is it suitable to use request.getParmater("o2") to get the parameter or is there any other method to get parmeter from httpppost?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `oxygenvalue` and `heartvalue` inside your Android code aren't just already `null`? You've by the way a huge SQL injection hole there. Fix it as well.

Comment: yes i sure that xygenvalue and heartvalue are not null since i println it out before doing namevaluepair and executing httppost, i even tried to hardcode a value for it but it also becomes null

sorry, "huge SQL injection hole there" what does it means and how can i solve it? many thanks!

Comment: one more question, can anyone sure that after i have sent the data  to the servlet, i need to save it to db first, and then when i am going to refresh my servlet page in browser the browser read the data stored in db? OR can i directly println the data out by using request.getParameter instead of saving it and retrieveing from db? 

Since my friend told me that i have to save to db first and then retrieve the data from db during runtime instead of directly println out the data in servlet? Is he true? anyway i have tried both method but still got null

Comment: You can see the output of e.printStackTrace() and other log calls in the Logcat view in Eclipse or by running `adb logcat` from the shell. The device needs to be connected to the computer (or be an emulator). Once you figure out what your actual error is you will be able to debug it much better.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is a Android issue to begin with at all by using something like [hackst.com](http://hackst.com) to post to your url and then report back.